# Unable to execute the Build.xml file using 'ant run' command in command prompt

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, selenium-webdriver

I am able to compile the build.xml file in command prompt without any error but when typed 'ant run' and clicked on enter nothing happens but the system is blank browser doesnt opens . Please assist me below is the build file im using and also i have configured correctly with all the environment variables

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE project[]>

<project name="ANT_TEST" default="usage" basedir=".">
    <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
        <property environment="env"/>    
        <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
        <property name="ws.jars" value="C:\Raghuveer\D-Drive\jar-files"/>
        <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
        <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
        <property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

    <target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
            <path id="classpath_jars">
                <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
            </path>
            <pathconvert pathsep=":" 
                property="test.classpath" 
                refid="classpath_jars"/>
        </target>
     <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
            <tstamp>
                <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
            </tstamp>
            <condition property="ANT" 
                value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat" 
                else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
                        <os family="windows" />
            </condition>

            <taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
                   classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

        </target>

        <!-- all -->
        <target name="all">
        </target>

        <!-- clean -->
        <target name="clean">
            <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
        </target>

        <!-- compile -->
         <!-- compile -->
            <target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
                <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
                    <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
                </delete>
                <echo message="making directory..."/>
                <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
                <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
                <echo message="compiling..."/>
                <javac 

                    debug="true" 
                    target="1.7" 
                    source="1.7"                    
                    destdir= "${test.dest}"
                    srcdir="${test.src}"                       
                    includeantruntime="false" 
                    classpath="${test.classpath}">


                </javac>

             <copy todir="${test.dest}">

                    <fileset dir="${test.src}" excludes="**/*.java"/>

               </copy>


              </target>


        <!-- build -->
        <target name="build" depends="init">
        </target>

        <!-- run -->
        <target name="run" depends="compile">

            <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${ws.home}/build" suitename="ANT_Suite">   
                <xmlfileset dir="test-output" includes="execute.xml"/>
            </testng>
             </target>
            <!--
            <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" groups="fast">
                <classfileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="example1/*.class"/>
            </testng>
            -->



    <target name="usage">
        <echo>
            ant run will execute the test
        </echo>
    </target>



    <path id="test.c">
            <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>

    </path>



    <target name="generateReport" >
        <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output">
        </mkdir>

        <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
            out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison" >

             <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
             <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>


        </xslt>
    </target>

    <!--using javax mailjar and javax activation jar trying to send report as zip file  -->

    <target name="sendMail" depends="generateReport">




    <zip destfile="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output.zip" basedir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

    <mail
    tolist="asdf@sdfa.com,asdfasd@adsf.com"
    from="gggg@gmail.com"
    subject="ANT_AUTO_Generated_EMAIL_.."
    mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"
    mailport="465"
    ssl="true"
    user="asdf@gmail.com"
    password="****">
    <attachments>
    <fileset dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/">
    <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
    </attachments>

    </mail>
    </target>
    </project>
```

Comment: pls post your stack trace are u getting any errors in cmd on ant run ??

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Vicky

Comment: I am not getting any error when i typed ant run in command prompt system goes blank and nothing happens

Comment: My guess would be that your `execute.xml` is empty or on some other location, resulting in no tests being run, though I would then expect that to be reflected in the output. Have you looked through http://seleniumeasy.com/ant-tutorials/how-to-run-testng-tests-using-build-xml-file and/or any other tutorial to get it running in the most basics of settings first? (PS: I fail to see how this is related to XSLT, as that is only used in your reporting, which is not part of your question).

Comment: I Checked my 'execute.xml' file its not empty nor its on some other location . i also googled and gon through many blogs everything seems to be correct , I doubt on the environmental variables configurations can you please correct me if i am wrong below is what i have configured.

Comment: ANT_HOME  and JAVA_HOME where in i have provided their paths and these two are created in environment variables/user variables. Created Testing_Home as '%CLASSPATH%;%TESTNG_HOME%\testng-6.8.jar' and in system variables path i have given the ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

Comment: system variables----classpath-----C:\Raghuveer\D-Drive\jar-files

system variables---path----;C:\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_79;%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Raghuveer\D-Drive\jar-files\testng-6.8\testng-6.8\testng-6.8.jar

Comment: Any suggestions guys...